# Help to show the limit of $a_n = -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}+a_{n-1}}$ is 1 using just the definition of convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, monotone-functions

I want to find the limit of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ given by
$$
a_1 =0, \quad a_n = -\frac{1}{2}  + \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}+a_{n-1}} \ .
$$
I know the limit exists as I have shown the sequence is increasing and it is bounded by 1. My guess would be that it converges to 1 but I struggle showing it from the definition although I believe that it would be possible. Taking some $\epsilon >0$, then
$$
\vert a_k-1 \vert = 1-a_k \overset{!}{<} \epsilon
$$
meaning that $a_k$ would have to be strictly greater than $1-\epsilon$. However I cannot get further than this. Can anyone help?

Comment: This uses that the limit can be moved inside the square root, right though?

Comment: it indeed use that fact that $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ is continuous over $\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Thanks for your input but as I have clarified in the title, I want to prove this using just the definition :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $u_n=1-a_n$, so that $u_0=1$ and $u_n=\dfrac{3}{2}-\sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4}-u_{n-1}}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

I assume that you proved by induction that $a_n\leq 1$ for all $n\geq 0$, so $u_n\geq 0$ for all $n\geq 0$.

Then for all $n\geq 1$, we have $0\leq u_n=\dfrac{u_{n-1}}{\dfrac{3}{2}+\sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4}-u_{n-1}}}\leq \dfrac{2}{3}u_{n-1}.$

By induction, you get $0\leq u_n\leq \left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Now you can use $\epsilon$'s if you want or use the squeeze theorem.