# Calculus limit prove of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am having problems with [this task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnTah.jpg).

Prove the existence and find the limit of the sequence  $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ $$\begin{cases}a_1=8\\a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n+3}\end{cases}$$

Can't find any help anywhere, I'm really stuck.

Should I start by proving that it's bounded? And how to prove such sequence is? I also tried with proving that it converges but guess it's too hard for me.

Comment: Hello, to type out the question in the link: type `$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$` and `$$\begin{cases}a_1=8\\a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n+3}\end{cases}$$` to get $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ and $$\begin{cases}a_1=8\\a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2a_n+3}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Prove that the sequence is bounded from bellow and is decreasing (by induction). Then .... [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292711/help-to-show-the-limit-of-a-n-frac12-sqrt-frac54a-n-1-is-1) post can help.

Comment: Assume that the sequence has indeed a limit, say $L$. Substitute it in the recursive relation, square both sides, and you get: $L^2 = 2L +3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first notice that our sequence is bounded below by $0$.  Let's try to show it's decreasing.

Notice that $a_{n+1}$ is a monotonically increasing function of $a_n$.  Notice also that $a_2 = \sqrt{19} < a_1$.  It follows that $a_3 < a_2$, and so on by induction that our sequence is decreasing.

So, our sequence converges; now, we only need to figure out what its limit is.  Our recurrence relation suggests to us an algebraic relation that the limit should obey:

Let $a$ be our limit.  Then, $a = \sqrt{2a + 3}$, so $(a - 3)(a + 1) = 0$, which has solutions $a=3$ and $a=-1$.  We can discard the negative solution (as we observed below, our sequence is strictly positive), and the only possibility is that our sequence converges to $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Banach/Picard fixed point theorem.

The idea is that $(a_n)_n$ is defined as $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where $\forall x \in R_+ \;f(x)=\sqrt{2x+3}$.

We can prove that $f'$ is bounded in R_+ by $k=1/\sqrt{3}<1$. Using finite Increment theorem we have $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \leq k \vert x-y\vert$.

By applying the Banach/Picard fixed point theorem : $f(x)=x$ has a unique solution and $(a_n)$ converges (the existence of the limit) to fixed point (the solution of $f(x)=x$). In this case the solution is 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Observe the terms of this sequence are *a priori* nonnegative. You can prove that, if $x\ge 0$, $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+3}\le x$ if & only if $x\ge 3$, and furthermore that $f\bigl([3,+\infty)\bigr)=[3,+\infty)$, so that you can apply the *monotone convergence theorem*.